# JQuery erase content of field with replace function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, replace

I want to replace the char `dot` by a `comma` in a Number field in a form.
I use the code :

```
<script>
$("form").keypress(function(e) {
    $("#prix_total").val($("#prix_total").val().replace(/\./g, ','));
});
</script>
```

The problem is the value is erased after entering `.` char. How to properly replace dot by comma ?

Comment: In fact you can not do that with a `type="number"` input.

Answer (score 0):

First you should change number to string with methods 'toString()' :

```
 <script>
    $("#prix_total").focusout(function(e) {
        $("#prix_total").val($("#prix_total").val().toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
    });
 </script>
```

'focusout()' Mean do that after stop entering or finished.
You can Test that so :

```
<script>
  $("form").keypress(function(e) {
       $("#prix_total").val($("#prix_total").val().toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
   });
</script>
```